# Using exec() in PHP as an specific system user

Tags: php, bash

When I use the following php script:

```
<?php
    echo 'I am '.exec('whoami').' user';
?>
```

on my localhost, the result is `I am nobody user` and is what I expect.

But when I use:

```
<?php
    echo 'I am '.exec('echo <PASSWD> | sudo -S -u <USER> whoami').' user';
?>
```

where `<PASSWD>` is my password and `<USER>` is my user name, the result is `I am user` and I expect to be `I am <USER> user`. How can I make it to work as I wish?

---

As a note, when I use `echo 'I am '.exec('echo <PASSWD> | sudo -S -u <USER> whoami').' user';` inside php interpreter (php -a), everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that is being used is the one running php/httpd process on the server. Depending on your server setup this could be Apache, root, or in FastCGI setups it can be any user or *no user*. This is a fallacy since there must always be a user. Typically shared hosting servers will try to circumvent allowing users to execute functions as a sudo user. This may be what you are experiencing.

Comment: Ok, this I experiecing. But my question is how can I make it to work (if there is a way)... When I use php interpreter is working.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this context, whoami will always return the user that is running the service, regardless of the username you are logged in with. The reason is because you are not running the script from a shell like you typically would, you are running the script from the server. The server is always the same user, so it will always be that. You could try using something like [PHP's FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) or [PHPSECLIB](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to connect from your script and print the user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

A straight answer is you may need to go via shell to use the pipes etc

- shell_exec..

For large scale applications, creating all those small processes is quite expensive.

IMO, a better solution is using these ::

- pcntl_fork
- posix_seteuid
- posix_setegid
- exec
- Optional proc_nice

The calls to `sudo` are technically running with *root* permission. So this is the same, in a more visible fashion..

I'm sure you don't need me to tell you that putting those passwords in your source is a bad idea.